# Problem with Real Digits and and getting the sum of digits

Tags: functions, number-theory, homework

I want to find the sum of the digits of the first 30 000 multiples of 31. I started  by first finding the multiples. Like this:

```
multiples31 = Length[Select[Range[1, 930000], Mod[#, 31] == 0 &]]
```

But after this part I'm really stuck. I have no clue of what to do (expect using the command the `RealDigits`).

Comment: It is not clear what your question is exactly. Are you trying to compute the sum of the digits for each multiple of 31?

Answer (score 5):

Assuming you trying to compute the sum of the digits for each of the first 30000 multiples of 31

```
Array[31*# &, 30000] // Map[Total[IntegerDigits[#]] &]
```